# jquery function not working in IE7 only

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, event-propagation

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sliding-buttons').click(slidingContent);
});

function slidingContent(e) {
    var boxID = $(this).attr('id'),
        boxName = $(this).attr('name');

    $('.sliding-holder#s-h-' + boxName).css({'display' : 'block'}).addClass('open');
    $('.sliding-content#s-c-' + boxName + '-' + boxID).css({'display' : 'block'}).addClass('open');
    $('.sliding-box#s-b-' + boxName).stop(true, true).animate({
        top:'0'
        },'slow');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

It's working in all browsers except, naturally, IE7. In IE7 it fails to stop the propagation.

I'm using the latest version of jquery (1.6.2) but have also tried 1.5.2.

I'm really at a loss here; there are no trailing commas (that I can see...) and I can't find the problem. I'd really appreciate some assistance!

MTIA.

Comment: none. it just fails to prevent the propagation.

Comment: do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: Skip IE7 :) It has just been used by 4.1% these days. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to skip the stupid thing! :-) Not sure I should though, at least until MS stops supporting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If slidingContent is a function, then you may want to treat it like a function, using parenthesis by calling it. Also, since you are referring to the original event inside the slidingContent function, you may need to pass the event as a function parameter (not sure about this though since I never used events like you are using.

```
$('.sliding-buttons').click( slidingContent(e) );
```

Comment: vivek's code incorporates your suggestion. unfortunately, it's still failing to prevent propagation.

Comment: Maybe you should try a different approach, you should use only a single event listener for the click event of the parent who contains all the children you want to be clicked. Then the event will propagate to the parent, and using e.target you can refer to the real element being clicked. This also save a lot of system resources and speed up code especially in old crappy IE7.

Comment: Yes, you're right; I should be doing that. The site is 99% done and to go back and rewrite all my functions would be regressive (although would be better practice). I've up-voted your comment.

Comment: I've selected your response as the answer, although for some unknown reason the function is now working in IE7. I don't understand why, and frankly I don't want to! It's IE7, it's working. :-)

Answer (score 1):

i am just guessing...can you try in this way...

```
$(function() {
    $('.sliding-buttons').click(function(e){
         var boxID = $(this).attr('id'),
        boxName = $(this).attr('name');

    $('.sliding-holder#s-h-' + boxName).css({'display' : 'block'}).addClass('open');
    $('.sliding-content#s-c-' + boxName + '-' + boxID).css({'display' : 'block'}).addClass('open');
    $('.sliding-box#s-b-' + boxName).stop(true, true).animate({
        top:'0'
        },'slow');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

   });
});
```

or you need to pass event object to called function in this way-

```
$('.sliding-buttons').click( slidingContent(e) );
```

Comment: can you post your html too..or jsfiddle?

Comment: yeah, i'm having probs connecting to jsfiddle atm. site looks as though it's down.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, I've up-voted your response as it was posted a couple of minutes after Jose's and I realise your answers were both relevant.